# iOS: offset byte pointer on a file?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working on being able to resume the upload of files in my iOS project. I'd like to be able to say something like 'begin this upload starting with an offset of 1000 bytes'. What's the best way to handle this problem? Getting a reference to the file is trivial. I'm not sure how to start an NSURLConnection though, using an offset.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about HTTP?  Resuming uploads is done by supplying a `Content-Range` HTTP header.  See [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.16) for details.  Essentially, you'll work out the correct header, then only supply the bytes for that range to the `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Actually that's one way of doing it. It depends on what the server you're working with is designed to do. In this case the server isn't using the Content-Range headers.